Example of Excellent rings of infinite Krull dimension?
Do there exists Excellent rings of  infinite Krull dimension?
If I understand correctly, Nagata's famous example of a Noetherian ring of infinite Krull dimension is not excellent...

Hiromu Tanaka proved that one of Nagata's examples of an infinite-dimensional Noetherian ring is excellent in Theorem 3.11 of

Hiromu Tanaka, Infinite dimensional excellent rings, Comm. Algebra 47 (2019), no. 2, 482–489; doi:10.1080/00927872.2018.1477952; MR 3935359.

